# Automate large number of parameters in OOP

Tags: python

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self, nome, morada, zona, pais):
        self.Nome = nome
        self.Morada = morada
        self.Zona = zona
        self.Pais = pais
        ...

    def save(self):
         ins = db.insert('tdemo', nome = self.Nome, morada = self.Morada, zona = self.Zona, pais = self.Pais)   
         if not ins:
             return False
```

---

```
if form.validate():
     client = Client(form.Nome.data, form.Morada.data, form.Zona.data, form.Pais.data)
     client.save()
```

This code works well with 4 parameters, but the real case has a large number (>15 parameters). Anyone has an idea to automate this without define each parameter?

Comment: Have you thought about passing the entire `form` object to the `Client` constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the entire form :

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self, form):
        self.Nome = form.nome.data
        self.Morada = form.morada.data
        self.Zona = form.zona.data
        self.Pais = form.pais.data

client = Client(form)
```

Comment: Creates coupling between the Client class and the structure of form. To test Client in isolation, this forces you to create a form. If you must do this, create a class method that takes a form object, and extract the data in that, returning a Client. But keep the Client constructor from being dependent on a UI type.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the following approach for any number of parameters:

```
parameters = {
    'nome': form.Nome.data,
    'morada': form.Morada.data,
    'zona': form.Zona.data,
    'pais': form.Pais.data,
}
client = Client(**parameters)
```

This should keep the code reasonable while still being explicit about what you pass to `Client`.